# rails calculating percent between two hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, hash

I have a two hashes looks

```
A = {2019.01 => 100, 2019.02 => 100, 2019.03 => 100, 2019.04 => 100} 

B = {2019.01 => 20, 2019.02 => 30, 2019.03 => 50, 2019.04 => 40}
```

and i need the result of

```
C = {2019.01 => 20%, 2019.02 => 30%, 2019.03 => 50%, 2019.04 => 40%}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your data as variables:

```
a = {2019.01 => 100, 2019.02 => 100, 2019.03 => 100, 2019.04 => 100} 
b = {2019.01 => 20, 2019.02 => 30, 2019.03 => 50, 2019.04 => 40}
```

If you need just the percentage from `b`, you can just [transform values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values):

```
b.transform_values{ |v| v.fdiv(100) }
#=> {2019.01=>0.2, 2019.02=>0.3, 2019.03=>0.5, 2019.04=>0.4}
```

If you need to divide by values of `a`, you could [merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge):

```
a.merge(b) { |k, o_v, n_v| n_v.fdiv(o_v) }
{2019.01=>0.2, 2019.02=>0.3, 2019.03=>0.5, 2019.04=>0.4}
```

When you need the string percentage, you can use string interpolation:

```
n = 0.2
"#{n*100}%"
#=> "20.0%"
```

Note: you are using floats as hash keys for what it looks like a date.